# JQuery slider next / previous buttons not working on the first image?

Tags: jquery, button, slideshow

I have a jQuery slide show with a previous and next button and it works ok BUT! When the page first loads and the buttons are pressed nothing happens! The buttons work on every other image in the slide show but not on the first image when the page is loaded / refreshed? I am not very good at jQuery and would appreciate any help at all...

I made a fiddle but the buttons are not working at all in the fiddle! You can however view the code and perhaps find this bug: jsfiddle.net/Margate/QB7W9/

Here is a link to the offending page where everything runs (except for the buttons on the 1st image!):  http://www.darrenmorton.com/example/index.html

Thank you in advance for any help,

Margate  : )

```
sliderint=1;
sliderNext=2;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slider>img#1").fadeIn(300);
    startSlider();
});

function startSlider(){
    count=$("#slider>img").size();

loop=setInterval(function(){

if(sliderNext>count){
    sliderNext=1;
    sliderInt=1;
}

$("#slider>img").fadeOut(300);
$("#slider>img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

sliderInt=sliderNext;
sliderNext=sliderNext+1

},15000)
}

function prev(){
    newSlide=sliderInt-1;
    showSlide(newSlide);
}

function next(){
    newSlide=sliderInt+1;
    showSlide(newSlide);
}


function stopLoop(){
    window.clearInterval(loop);
}

function showSlide(id){
    stopLoop();
    if(id>count){
    id=1;
}else if(id<1){
id=count;
}

$("#slider>img").fadeOut(300);
$("#slider>img#" + id).fadeIn(300);

sliderInt=id;
sliderNext=id+1;
startSlider();
}

$("#slider>img").hover(
function (){
    stopLoop();
},
function(){
startSlider();
}
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

original initialization

```
sliderint=1;
```

change it to

```
sliderInt=1;
```

And it would work

Comment: :  ) Fixed!!!! My word! I'm sitting here laughing because it was just the difference between an i and I and I have been pulling my hair out for the past two days trying to fix this! Just shows how meticulous code is!  I'm off to study Jquery more, I have spent hours trying to fix this. I'm not very good so would never have seen that in a million years... Thank you so much for your help. I hope that others can learn from this about how detailed coding really is...

Answer (score 1):

In your js initialize the following variable

Current

```
sliderint=1;
sliderNext=2;
```

update it to

```
var sliderint=1;
var sliderNext=2;
```

and make `sliderint` consistent it is `sliderint` and `sliderInt` at other place

Check http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/QB7W9/1/

Comment: Check the updated answer, have made js fiddle working

Comment: Raunak - that works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help. I will keep this copy in my files for future reference. Kind Regards,